# Android Development: seekbar count down!

Tags: android

Is it possible, if yes how, how do i go from progress 100 to 1 without the user doing anything.

Like for every .05sec seekbar.setProgress(-=1)
So without the user doing anything the seekbar will go down until it reach 1.

Please anser how to do this

Thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public Async(Context ctx) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dialog.incrementProgressBy(1);

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    while (i < 1000) {

        publishProgress(1);
        i++;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  For the sake of learning: what if I didn't use a ProgressDialog, but instead has a ProgressBar on a view in an activity?

Comment: Umm, that doesn't really make any sense. Instead of using an asynctask then you'd just call your activity. You can have a progressbar in a view and then set the dialog to display that view.

Comment: To clarify, I mean if it was setup like such: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-do-i-load-chunks-of-data-from-an-assest-manager-during-a-loading-screen I have a loading screen with a progress bar.  I pop off things in a stack to load bitmaps, sounds, etc. into memory.  Should I consider switching it to AsyncTask like you said or leave it as is with the manual threads? (I guess I should actually ask a question about this)

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you're doing all that background work in different threads, you might want to consider doing manual threading. If you're just loading everything in a single thread, just use an asynctask and put it all in doInBackground() and then update the progress after each function.

Answer (score 0):

Something roughly like this (note: may not compile):

```
private int progressStatus = 100;

new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (progressStatus > 1) 
                {
                    progressStatus = doSomeWork();

                    //---Update the progress bar---
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() {
                        // Do your thing here when it's done
                    }
                });
            }    

            private int doSomeWork() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    //---simulate doing some work---
                    Thread.sleep(50);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int progress = progressStatus - 1;

                return progress;
            }

        }).start();
```

Comment: Got errors i cant figure out how. where did you get the code. you got a link?

Comment: @carefacerz I pulled it out of one of my apps that was doing a loading screen 0 to 100.  I just reversed the counter.  See my example at gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3380/47

Comment: The tutorial I pulled it form is here under Progress View http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views

Comment: -1 just for the fact that you're not using an asynctask and instead writing 60 lines of code with a bunch of runnables

Comment: @Falmarri Would you like to provide a better example?  I would like to learn here, I just shared what I found before

Comment: And simply choosing to not use AsyncTask does not necessarily make it wrong http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: @Bryan: of course not, but this situation is pretty much EXACTLY what the asynctask class was made for. I'd remove my downvote if I could since it was pretty unfair =\

Comment: @Falmarri no problem, I learned something from your comment anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be forced to write your own progress bar. Here's an example: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-progressbar-for-android.html

There's more than one way to do it...

Comment: i think bryan-denny have something on the way. If you can help that code please.